# Whitespace around linebreaked text

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

Here is the fiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hp61pthk/3/

The code is:

```css
    h2.nadpis {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 2.5em;
    }
    h2.nadpis:after {
      display: block;
      content: '';
      height: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid #2C3E50;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    h2.nadpis span {
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 15px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
 <h2 class="nadpis"><span>Long heading long heading</span></h2>
<h2 class="nadpis"><span>Short heading</span></h2>
```

what i want to achieve is to have a heading with lines on both sides in the middle of text.

If you enter short text it works, but when i enter longer text in span breaks the line correctly but its width remains as it was full-length. Is this a normal behaviour? How can i say to span to have the width exactly

Comment: didnt get you...what are you trying to achieve???

Comment: Run the snippet and don't expand to full page. I think the OP wants to see the line on either side of the heading when the text begins to wrap, which it doesn't.

Comment: Yes hungerstar is right. You have to shrink the page so the long heading breaks into two lines. Then you will se that the span is not as width as text.

Comment: Really? Noone knows the solution for this? So it looks it is a normal behaviour. =(

Answer (score 0):

My contribution:

> http://jsfiddle.net/hp61pthk/13/

```
h2.nadpis {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2C3E50;
}

h2.nadpis span {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```